# Why those nearly the same codes get a different result in php's array_walk + ksort?

Tags: php, ksort, array-walk

I want to sort a multi-array by key, those data come form front end somehow will be mess up in an random sort.
So I must make the data sorted, at first I natural use the combine 'array_walk($array, "ksort")'. Work fine at simple array data, while dealing a multi-array, it work wrong.
Finally, I solve it by loop ksort.
But I have no clue why the nearly same codes get a different result.
Someone help? Thx

```
    $arr = [
        ['identifier_num' => 1, 'form_id' => 3, 'is_view' => 1, 'in_time' => '3', 'model_num' => 44],
        ['form_id' => 1, 'identifier_num' => 3, 'in_time' => 1, 'is_view' => '3', 'model_num' => 44],
        ['b' => 1, 'a' => '2'],
    ];
    $a2 = $arr;

    array_walk($arr, 'diydiy');
    var_dump($arr);

    array_walk($a2, 'ksort');
    var_dump($a2);

    function diydiy(&$a)
    {
        ksort($a);
    }
```

The result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'form_id' => int 3
      'identifier_num' => int 1
      'in_time' => string '3' (length=1)
      'is_view' => int 1
      'model_num' => int 44
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'form_id' => int 1
      'identifier_num' => int 3
      'in_time' => int 1
      'is_view' => string '3' (length=1)
      'model_num' => int 44
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => string '2' (length=1)
      'b' => int 1
D:\WWW\t.php:13:
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'form_id' => int 3
      'identifier_num' => int 1
      'in_time' => string '3' (length=1)
      'is_view' => int 1
      'model_num' => int 44
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'model_num' => int 44
      'is_view' => string '3' (length=1)
      'in_time' => int 1
      'identifier_num' => int 3
      'form_id' => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => string '2' (length=1)
      'b' => int 1
```

Comment: I test your code and the result is [OK](https://repl.it/KXUT/0), what is your version of PHP ?

Comment: Looks like a bug that was fixed in PHP 7.

Comment: You can try it in different versions here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ec4f2d4bd3957536b9244f2e97b462b7d749497

Comment: Maybe it's [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48423)

Comment: My php version is 5.6.27-nts but in phpstudy, I get wrong result every time @kip , but my colleague work well , I totally confused.

Comment: Did you get the wrong result? @Barmar

Comment: @ccbility I get the wrong result with PHP 5, the right result with PHP 7.

Comment: Yes @Barmar is a bug, @ccbility you can get the result with an anonymus function `array_walk($a2, function($a) { ksort($a); });` is more clean.